# Bad request when trying to upload a file through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

I am trying to upload an image to my backend. I need to send three things along with this image - file (a url) and title. I have tried doing it but getting error saying 400 bad request. In the network tab I see a response like this
[image]

This is my code

```
posterFile = e.target.files;
selectedPoster = posterFile[0];


uploadPoster() {
        var blobPosterFile = selectedPoster;
        console.log("U called me?")
        var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("fileToUpload", blobPosterFile);

    var that = this;
    let token;
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://www.backend.sample.forexom.com/api/v1/videos/",
        "method": "POST",
        processData: false,
        "credentials": 'include',
        "headers": {
            Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
        },
        "data": {
            "file": JSON.stringify(videoURL),
            "poster": formData,
            "title": JSON.stringify(selectedFile.name)
        },
        success:( response, textStatus, jQxhr )=> {
            //this.props.tokenAction(response.auth_token);
            console.log("poster uploaded")
        }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {

    });
}
```

Update

Tried appending other data to formData like this, but getting same error

```
uploadPoster() {
        var blobPosterFile = selectedPoster;
        console.log("U called me?")
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", videoURL)
        formData.append("poster", blobPosterFile);
        formData.append("title", selectedFile.name)

        var that = this;
        let token;
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://www.backend.trigger.tessact.com/api/v1/videos/",
            "method": "POST",
            processData: false,
            "credentials": 'include',
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
            },
            "data": formData,

            success:( response, textStatus, jQxhr )=> {
                //this.props.tokenAction(response.auth_token);
                console.log("poster uploaded")
            }
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {

        });
    }
```

Comment: A 400 error means the server couldn't understand the request. The problem lies on the serverside, and that what the server is expecting, and what it's receiving, doesn't compute. The reason is that you can only send formData as the **only** data to the server, if you want to add more information, you have to append it to the formData object you're sending.

Comment: It seems that you are not giving any values to your data variables (i.e. `videoURL`, `formData`, `selectedFile.name`), double check them. If the value is present, then something may be off in your backend.

Comment: @adeneo But backend is expecting three fields. How can I do it by appending?

Comment: @Gerry they have values.

Comment: @ApurvG - You're already appending to the formData in your code, it's the same to append the other values as key/value pairs, and then just do `data : formData`. You can **only** send the formData, you can't use an object as data for jQuery's `$.ajax` when you've disabled `processData` as that object won't be converted to x-www-urlencoded etc.

Comment: @adeneo can you please check my updated ques. I did what you are asking, but getting the same error. Please suggest what am I doing wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Removing content type from headers and the code in my updated question solved the issue. Here is the code

```
uploadPoster() {
        var blobPosterFile = selectedPoster;
        console.log("U called me?")
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", videoURL)
        formData.append("poster", blobPosterFile);
        formData.append("title", selectedFile.name)
    var that = this;
    let token;
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://www.backend.trigger.tessact.com/api/v1/videos/",
        "method": "POST",
        processData: false,
        "credentials": 'include',
        "headers": {

            Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
        },
        "data": formData,

        success:( response, textStatus, jQxhr )=> {
            //this.props.tokenAction(response.auth_token);
            console.log("poster uploaded")
        }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {

    });
}
```